# How to edit a csv file using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, max, sample

So I have this data file I generated from a bigger one. Now I want to add a summary to the new file which includes MAX MIN MEAN all of these functions but i don't know how to write it into the file after generating it

```
file1 = file.sample(int(sample))
file1_max = file1.max()

file1.to_csv( Path,index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Welcome to our community! I have a question please : file1 and file are them pandas dataframes ?

Comment: yes, file is a big data frame and I'm taking a sample from it. I want to add to file1 functions or new rows is that possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code shows mean, max, min and other stats:

```py
file1.describe()
```